# Add a semi-transparent layer on top of a div

Tags: html, css

I would like to allow my user to click on the card to "cancel it". I can take care of the JS, but I am wondering what's the best way to add a "red opaque overlay" on top of the card after the user clicks it.

So ideally I can write a css class such as but also make it that it's not simply transparent at 40% but also slightly "red". And I don't want to create another dive that wraps the whole card if possible.

```
.card-deactivated{
  opacity:40%
}
```

```css
.card{
  max-width:300px;
  min-width:200px;
  height: 350;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px 0px 20px;
  gap: 10px;
  
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /* Gray/4px */
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(41, 41, 41, 0.08);
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.card-img{
  order: 0;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:2rem;
}

.card-title{
  align-self:center;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
  
}

.card-description{
  
  align-self:center;
  margin:0px 20px 1rem;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class='card'>
    <img class='card-img' alt='Card Image' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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'>
    <h3 class='card-title'>Name Surname</h3>
    <p class='card-description'>This is a long descriptionThis is     a long descriptionThis is a long descriptionThis is a long descriptionThis is a long description </p>
  </div>
```

**Edit**
I am achieving some sort of result by leveraging this css but I don't think I am doing it "right"...or at least in the best possible way.

```
.card{
  max-width:300px;
  min-width:200px;
  height: 350;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px 0px 20px;
  gap: 10px;
  
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /* Gray/4px */
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(41, 41, 41, 0.08);
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.overlay-selected::after {
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: .3;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #eaee44, #eaee44);
}
```

Comment: you may simply add a class that alters the appearance in the way you want. Also, that new class can bring the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements into play which could allow more customization.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that's what I thought I was supposed to do...but I am not sure how to do it with the before after pseudo-elements...any suggestion?

Comment: You may provide a [mre] so we can reproduce your example and follow along with insights on how to achieve your goal.

Comment: I actually have the code-pen link in the post. Or are you actually saying it's unclear what I am trying to do?

Comment: Actually you can make [Runnable Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets) directly within your question.

Comment: Thanks, I added it. Any idea of how to solve the issue as well?

Comment: I have posted an answer, please check if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using one of the pseudo-elements, either `::before` or `::after`, that will act as an overlay when the user clicks on the `.card` element.

Basically, we'll initially style that overlay, we'll use the `::after` pseudo-element, and place it behind the `.card` element using `z-index` of `-1` so that the overlay is hidden initially. When a click occurs, we add a class, let's call it `is-canceled`, to the `.card` element that simply sets the `z-index` of the overlay to a higher value (like `2` or `999`) so that the overlay appears on top of the `.card` element and act as the intended overlay.

To make the overlay transition smoothly, we'll initially set its `background-color` to `transparent` and override that when the `is-canceled` class is attached to the `.card` element. When the `is-canceled` class is attached to the `.card` element, we'll set the `background-color` to a reddish background (something like `rgba(255, 0, 0, .7)`. Using the `transition` property we can instruct the browser to have a smooth transition when the `is-canceled` is added/removed from the `.card` element.

To illustrate, here's alive demo that allows you to toggle the overlay when you click on the `.card` element:

```js
const card = document.querySelector('.card');

card.addEventListener('click', () => card.classList.toggle('is-canceled'));
```

```css
.card {
  position: relative; /* required to correctly position the overlay */
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px 0px 20px;
  gap: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(41, 41, 41, 0.08);
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* initial overlay styles */
.card::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all .4s 0s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* styles to be applied to the overlay when the "is-canceled" class is added */
.card.is-canceled::after {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .7);
  z-index: 999;
}

.card-img {
  order: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.card-title {
  align-self: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card-description {
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0px 20px 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-img" alt="Card Image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250">
  <h3 class="card-title">Name Surname</h3>
  <p class="card-description">This is a long descriptionThis is a long descriptionThis is a long descriptionThis is a long descriptionThis is a long description </p>
</div>
```

The above demo is just for demonstration purposes and you're invited to build upon it and customize it the way you see fit.